# Getting column of cell from context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

So far I have:

```
private void FilterItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the clicked MenuItem
        MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;

        //Get the ContextMenu to which the menuItem belongs
        ContextMenu contextMenu = (ContextMenu)menuItem.Parent;

        //Find the placementTarget
        DataGridRow rowItem = (DataGridRow)contextMenu.PlacementTarget;

        DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)rowItem.DataContext;
        DataRow row = dr.Row;
        string value = dr[0].ToString();
        string col = row.Table.Columns[0].ColumnName;

        Console.WriteLine(rowItem);
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        Console.WriteLine(col);
        Console.WriteLine(e.OriginalSource);
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
```

This works great, but I don't want 0, I want the column index of the cell that the context menu was selected for. From my google fu I have been unable to discern a concrete method for extracting the column. Information from e hasn't been particularly useful; the two values returned are System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem Header:Filter Items.Count:0
System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs

Any help will be very appreciated.

edit: current XAML

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="Grid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Margin="20,55,20,40" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridCollection.SourceCollection}">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderContextMenu">
                <MenuItem Header="Filter" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
            </ContextMenu>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderContextMenu}"/>
            </Style>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="rowContextMenu">
                <MenuItem Header="Filter" Click="FilterItem_Click"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource rowContextMenu}" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

The context menu in question is the one on the DataGridRow

Comment: Why not to use `DataGridCell` as `PlacementTarget` instead of `DataGridRow`?

Comment: It is unable to cast: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell"

Comment: You didn't understand me. Set context menu on `DataGridCell` rather than on `DataGridRow`. `DataGridCell` has `Column` property.

Comment: I wondered if you meant that after I replied so I tried that as well, but when I changed it it returned something like "cannot set property intended for DataGridRow". It seems to particularly want a DataGridRow, I'm not sure why

Comment: I am thick and you sir are a genius, thank you! I wasn't changing RowStyle to CellStyle the first time, which is why I got that error. Works perfectly now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer based on Maxim's comment:

Change XAML to:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource rowContextMenu}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

And in C#:

```
        // Get the clicked MenuItem
        MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;

        //Get the ContextMenu to which the menuItem belongs
        ContextMenu contextMenu = (ContextMenu)menuItem.Parent;

        //Find the placementTarget
        DataGridCell cellItem = (DataGridCell)contextMenu.PlacementTarget;

        DataGridColumn col = cellItem.Column;
        int index = Grid.Columns.IndexOf(col);

        DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)cellItem.DataContext;
        DataRow row = dr.Row;
        string value = dr.Row.ItemArray[index].ToString();
        string column = col.Header.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(value);
        Console.WriteLine(column);
```